# WebSocket connection to 'wss://hostname/' failed in Next.js 12

Tags: nginx, next.js

I'm using NGINX for hosting my web app, however I'm getting the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/_next/webpack-hmr' failed
```

after upgrade to Next.js 12 while running my app in dev mode on url https://example.com. I have tried the most common solution presented in Google.

First, I have added that to nginx.conf:

```
location /_next/webpack-hmr {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/_next/webpack-hmr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

However it did not help, also I have tried adding asssetPrefix to next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    ...,
    assetPrefix: 'https://example.com',
    ...,
}
```

And it also did not help with my issue. Any tips or advices are appreciated